# shared_buffers and wal_buffers values

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5.20 on ubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit

Our production server with 100 GB RAMs and we have thousands of concurrent users. I changed the shared_buffers value to be 25% of total RAMs so shared_buffers = 25GB, so it will be better and effective if I changed the wal_buffers value to be 3% of the total of shared buffers so finally it will be wal_buffers = 768MB? or it is just a silly and should be 16 MB only ?

Comment: What are the concurrent users doing?  wal_buffers is not really relevant unless you are doing large write transactions, and even then it is rarely worthwhile to change the default setting.

Comment: Read processes more than write

Answer (score 0):

`wal_buffers` far in excess of 16MB is just silly.

Make sure that the application uses a connection pool.